# Why there is ban on user having reputation below 15 to post image?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, images

I am thinking about what happens when new people join Stack Overflow.  When they ask questions, sometimes they need to post a screenshot, but they can't do that; sometimes they feel that Stack Overflow can't help them.

Why do you need 15 points to post an image?

Comment: Spammers would **love** to show you their Viagra pills in full colour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To be honest if new users could post **any** picture I think adverts for pills would be on the tamer side

Comment: I'm still on the fence with this one. It would make the spam much more obvious and in return flagged to death sooner.

Comment: @slhck O look, what are those two doing? That doesn't have anything to do with java. Well I'll just flag this. O no my boss just came in

Comment: @slhck that's actually not a bad point.I do sometimes agree with letting people create low-hanging fruit to squash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is to prevent spam/offensive images being posted (very few bots get reputation above 15). If you need to post a screen shot just upload it and include a link in your question. As pointed out by Molot; if those links are useful a higher rep user will usual edit the image in.

[imgur](http://imgur.com/) is what is used internally by stack exchange anyway and uploading images does not require registration. I recommend using that until you get your 15 reputation

Comment: Also, most of 2k+ users that founds question interesting do stop by to edit linked images into posts. At least on Drupal Answers.